# Figures as entries in a List

Tags: numbering, lists

I have to include figures in a list. When I prepare such a list the numbers are seen below the corresponding entries. How can I rectify this issue?[image: Figures as the entries in a numbered list]

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With use of the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Name}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item First item
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{1.png} 
\caption{}\label{subfig:1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{2.png}
\caption{}\label{subfig:2}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\item Second item
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{3.png}
\caption{}\label{subfig:3}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{4.png}
\caption{}\label{subfig:4}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not whole solution but good example I think:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Name}
\begin{enumerate}

\item First item
%\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\center{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{1.png} \\ a)}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\center{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{2.png} \\ b)}
\end{minipage}
 
\end{figure}
%\end{center}

\item Second item
  %\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\center{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{3.png} \\ c)}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\center{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{4.png} \\ d)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
  %\end{center}
 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely placing the images inside a `figure` environment that is allowed to float. You don't have to; set the images inside a `tabular` - here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item
  \begin{tabular}{ c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-b} \\
    (a) $G_1$ &
      (b) $H_1$
  \end{tabular}

  \item \leavevmode
  
  \begin{tabular}{ c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-b} \\
    (a) $G_1$ &
      (b) $H_1$
  \end{tabular}
  
  \item
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip,valign=t]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip,valign=t]{example-image-b} \\[2.2\normalbaselineskip]
    (a) $G_2$ &
      (b) $H_2$
  \end{tabular}

  \item
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-b} \\
    (a) $G_2$ &
      (b) $H_2$
  \end{tabular}

  \item
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-b} \\
    (a) $G_2$ &
      (b) $H_2$
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```